# Android Facebook SDK getRequestForPagedResults always null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I´m trying to crawl through every Picture a Page has uploaded to Facebook with Pagination. Although, the response of Facebook has got Pagination Details both in the response and in the Graph Explorer Tool, the method response.getRequestForPagedResults alwways returns null.
Does anyone know why?

Here is my code

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(accessToken, "/" + timelinePhotos,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    GraphRequest nextRequest =      response.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
                    Log.e("HALLO", response.toString());
                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject();
                    JSONArray data = null;

                        if(nextRequest!=null){
                            nextRequest.setCallback(this);
                            nextRequest.executeAsync();
                        }else{
                            Log.e("HI", "ICHBINFEDDIIICH");
                        }


                }
            });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "photos{likes.limit(0).summary(true)}");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

Here is the response I get from facebook

```
 01-04 04:42:03.564: E/HALLO(983): {Response:  responseCode: 200, 
    graphObject: {"id":"853505791349630","photos":{"data":  
    [{"id":"1187285891304950","likes":{"summary":
{"can_like":true,"total_count":678,"has_liked":false},"data":[]}},  
{"id":"1185272354839637","likes":{"summary":
{"can_like":true,"total_count":2245,"has_liked":false},"data":[]}},
{"id":"1184689078231298","likes":{"summary"
:{"can_like":true,"total_count":3242,"has_liked":false},"data":[]}}, ....lots of more IDS


"paging":{"cursors":    {"after":"MTE2NzU2MDEyOTk0NDE5MwZDZD","before":"MTE4NzI4NTg5MTMwNDk1MAZDZD"},"ne
xt":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.5\/853505791349630\/photos?
access_token=XXX
jKzSgbusvQKMXtXmIsgl01T
vTEPQBZCp3XhM8ieGCYclmmuc7FzVDyl8jcJTW&
fields=likes.limit%280%29.summary%28true%
29&limit=25&after=MTE2NzU2MDEyOTk0NDE5MwZDZD"}}}, error: null}
```

So, as you can see, there clearly is a Paging-Information, so why is my nextRequest alway null?

Comment: Copy the value of the `next` URL, remove the backslash-escaping, and then request it in your browser – what do you get then?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to working somehow?

I am facing the same issue with v2.8 and this is November, so apparently it has not been fixed in the last 11 months.