# Facebook graph API /me/friends not returns all friends who authorized app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

After a long surf i have realized Graph API `/me/friends` only returns the person's friends who also use the app.anyway i need answer from an experienced one

***Any possibility to fetch all friends of a user ?***

Now my second query I have used the following code for fetching friends of a user after verifying and approved `user_friends` permission by team facebook and also I'm logging in with the `user_friends` permission.

```
 /* make the API call */
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/me/friends",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                     /* handle the result *
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Response

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"summary":{"total_count":572},"data":[]}, error: null}.
```

I have friends in my list whose also uses the same app but ain't get their information also you can see in the above response only `total_count` were returning.

What's going wrong, Can anyone help me out ?

***Update***

After some debugging now I'm getting only details of single friend in response while i have friends more than that whose using the app.why it won't return the other friends details ? any idea ?

Also when i debugged with [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken), it tells that the user have `user_friends` scope.still ain't get the expected response.

Comment: No, it isn't possible, and this is well documented since nearly two years.

Comment: Hmm,thank you. got the expected answer.do u have any idea why ain't get the friends details too those who are using the app ?

Comment: *The same app* means your app? If so, then they might not have granted the `user_friends` permission. Have you inspected the Access Token and verified that it really contains the permission? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: yes I have already loggined using my friends account in the app named `Zodiva` and also facebook team approved  `user_friends` permission after verifying my app that i have submitted for review.and done login with permission like  `private final String PERMISSIONS[] = {"public_profile", "user_birthday", "email", "user_photos","user_friends"};                                                                           LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList(PERMISSIONS));`

Comment: Yes, but please check the issued access token really contain the permission

Comment: Sorry i dint understand, how it can be check ?

Comment: Use the debug tool I linked above and copy the access token into it.

Comment: @Tobi , yay !  after a fresh installation now I'm getting only details of single friend in response while i have friends more than that whose using the app?

Comment: What installation? I can't really help you any further... I noted all possible problem points. Please go and check the access tokens

Comment: I mean after uninstalling and reinstalling the app instead an update. Thanks for your time @Tobi

Comment: if you have game app then you got all friend..otherwise don't  get fb friend name

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating permissions in an existing application then exiting users will have to logout and login again with new set of permissions with new code.